# WebView2 deployment too big with the fixed version

Tags: wpf, deployment, webview2

We're working on deployment options an app using WebView2 control.
We don't have an option to use EverGreen installer but to go with the fixed version.

However, i noticed that fixed version contains too many binaries and making up to 400+ MBs(almost 1/2 GB) on our customer's machine.

Any idea to keep it at minimum? Or use only the required binaries?

Comment: You can use **neutralinojs** as alternative. It's only about **2MB**.

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea to keep it at minimum? Or use only the required binaries?

No. All binaries are required. If disk space is a requirement, then you should use the Evergreen Runtime distribution mode.

If you cannot do this for whatever reason and instead decide to go with the fixed version runtime distribution mode, more disk space *will be* required on the client.

I am afraid you cannot exclude some required binaries and expect the component to work as expected.